# Keras Image Augmentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Can someone please help me out figure what is the sequence of applying 
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

For example I have:

```
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test # these are my data sets
```

How do I augment `x_train` AND `x_test` using "datagen" ?

Do I do the following:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...stuff...)
datagen.fit(x_train)
datagen.fit(x_test)
```

Then I create my Neural Network Model:

```
model = Sequential()
```

.
.
.

then

```
model.compile(...stuff...)
```

then

```
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
samples_per_epoch=len(x_train), nb_epoch=100, verbose=2, validation_data=
(x_test, y_test), nb_worker=1)
```

Comment: I hope my formatting and question is clear.

Comment: I think you've to flow the validation images too or create separate generators for train and validation. [more info](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)